# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError On a google app engine & maven

Tags: java, rest, maven, google-app-engine, jersey

I'm building a google app engine website with server currently having this error, i googled it and found several fixes but none of them worked so I'm thinking its a different problem

I'm also using maven and a rest server

```
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/Container
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:268)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:262)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:222)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:213)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 43 more
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-ALPHA</version>

    <groupId>pt.unl.fct.di.nextech.fixtr</groupId>
    <artifactId>fixtr</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <app.id>fixtr-nextech</app.id>
        <app.version>1</app.version>
        <appengine.sdk.version>1.9.51</appengine.sdk.version>
        <appengine.version>${appengine.sdk.version}</appengine.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.133.v201611104</gcloud.plugin.version>

        <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>war</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fixtr-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>pt.unl.fct.di.nextech.fixtr.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fixtr-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem, it was probably a corrupted jar, i deleted all of the jars and downloaded them with maven again and it worked fine.